# Add a near-identical element to header.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress website for a doctor who wants his phone number and fax number listed in the header. The theme I'm using just lists the phone number in the header, so I'm trying to replicate that feature with the little PHP knowledge I have and put the fax number on a separate line beneath the phone number in the header.php of my child theme.

I've tried copying and pasting the get_theme_mod function and substituting "faxnumber" for "telephonenumber", but not sure if that actually does anything to modify the theme, or if I have to dip into functions.php or some other file to actually create a fax-related theme mod. I'm also probably butchering the syntax (I really have to learn PHP).

Here's the relevant code from the header.php file:

```
<div class="header-contact">
    <?php
    if ( get_theme_mod( 'medica_lite_general_contactinfo_telephonetitle', 'Telephone' ) ) {
        echo esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'medica_lite_general_contactinfo_telephonetitle', 'Telephone' ) ) . '<br />';
    } else {
        echo '<br />';
    }

    if ( get_theme_mod( 'medica_lite_general_contactinfo_telephonenumber', '+1 223 456 23' ) ) {
        echo '<a href="tel:'. esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'medica_lite_general_contactinfo_telephonenumber', '+1 223 456 23' ) ) .'" title="'. esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'medica_lite_general_contactinfo_telephonetitle', 'Telephone' ) ) .'"><i class="icon-phone"></i> '. get_theme_mod( 'medica_lite_general_contactinfo_telephonenumber', '+1 223 456 23' ) .'</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<div style="margin-top: 24px;"></div>';
    }
    ?>
```

How would I create a new feature that displays the fax number beneath the phone number? I'd ideally like the fax number to be a different size than the phone number, so it'd have to be in a different class.

Comment: This seems needlessly complicated. If the doctor doesn't need the phone number to be editable via the Admin (usually, that's the case), you can simply add the phone number as plain HTML into the header. Otherwise, it's impossible for us to know how the theme is handling dynamic phone numbers in the header...so it'll be pretty difficult to help you modify that functionality.

Comment: As @rnevius stated. Unless you really want to add a new function to add "Fax Number" as a customise option, you could just echo the fax number underneath the  phone number.

Comment: Excellent -- thank you both so much. I've successfully added the fax number to the header and the footer using HTML, and then styled it with CSS. Looks great. One additional question: Adding a whole "get_theme_mod" function would create a customizable option that can be accessed from WP's backend, correct?